# Translate CIM, C++ and VARIANT types

Tags: c++, visual-c++, variant, wbem

Here is a list of CIM types, I need to know the equivalent in C++ and VARIANT types.

CIM_ILLEGAL

CIM_EMPTY

CIM_SINT8

CIM_UINT8

CIM_SINT16

CIM_UINT16

CIM_SINT32

CIM_UINT32

CIM_SINT64

CIM_UINT64

CIM_REAL32

CIM_REAL64

CIM_BOOLEAN

CIM_STRING

CIM_DATETIME

CIM_REFERENCE

CIM_CHAR16

CIM_OBJECT

CIM_FLAG_ARRAY

Comment: Voted to close as too broad/shows no effort.

Comment: I posted the question because I've wanted this info a few times and found today in a really annoying format. I thought I'd post it here so that when I / anyone Googles it next time the information is available more easily. http://www.delphigroups.info/3/4/53283.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CIM: CIM_ILLEGAL

C++: -

VARIANT: -

---

CIM: CIM_EMPTY

C++: -

VARIANT: VT_EMPTY

---

CIM: CIM_SINT8

C++: signed char

VARIANT: VT_I1

---

CIM: CIM_UINT8

C++: unsigned char

VARIANT: VT_UI1

---

CIM: CIM_SINT16

C++: signed short

VARIANT: VT_I2

---

CIM: CIM_UINT16

C++: unsigned short

VARIANT: VT_UI2

---

CIM: CIM_SINT32

C++: signed int

VARIANT: VT_I4

---

CIM: CIM_UINT32

C++: unsigned int

VARIANT: VT_UI4

---

CIM: CIM_SINT64

C++: signed __int64

VARIANT: VT_I8

---

CIM: CIM_UINT64

C++: unsigned __int64

VARIANT: VT_UI8

---

CIM: CIM_REAL32

C++: float

VARIANT: VT_R4

---

CIM: CIM_REAL64

C++: double

VARIANT: VT_R8

---

CIM: CIM_BOOLEAN

C++: bool

VARIANT: VT_BOOL

---

CIM: CIM_STRING

C++: BSTR, WideString

VARIANT: VT_BSTR

---

CIM: CIM_DATETIME

C++: time_t, TDateTime

VARIANT: VT_DATE

---

CIM: CIM_REFERENCE

C++: -

VARIANT: -

---

CIM: CIM_CHAR16

C++: wchar_t

VARIANT: VT_BSTR or VT_I2

---

CIM: CIM_OBJECT

C++: -

VARIANT: VT_UNKNOWN or VT_DISPATCH, depending on the object type

---

CIM: CIM_FLAG_ARRAY

C++: -

VARIANT: VT_ARRAY combined with another VT flag specifying the array type

Comment: CIM_UINT32 does not map to VT_UI4; it maps to VT_I4.

Comment: Do you have a page describing that? I'll change my answer if you could show it.